# Python Error - AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, python-3.x

=====Functioning code=====

(Omission)

```
contents = soup.find('table').find_all('a')


for i in contents:            
        print("---------------------------")
        link = i.find("td", class_= "cafecoffee").find_all("a")[0]
        print("link :")
        print("naver.com" + link)

        title = i.find("td")
        print("title:",title.text)
```

=====Non-functioning code=====

(Omission)

```
contents = soup.find('table').find_all('a')


for i in range(1,52): # <<<<changed
        print("---------------------------")
        link = i.find("td", class_= "cafecoffee").find_all("a")[0]
        print("link :")
        print("naver.com" + link)

        title = i.find("td")
        print("title:",title.text)
```

I don't know what the problem is, could you please help me, seniors?

I haven't made any attempts. It's only been an hour since I learned the language.

Comment: You are calling find on an integer, you need to index `contents` using `i`

Comment: Thnak you Tyler Liu !!

Comment: It told you exactly what your mistake was.  In the second version, `i` is an integer, right?  So what do you expect `i.find` to do?  It gives you an error, because integers have no `find` method.  Which is exactly what it told you (no attribute 'find').

Comment: Thank you  Tom Karzes, I am still a beginner, I will search more. Sorry.

Comment: I solved Thnak you everyone. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'find'* tells you exactly what the problem is:

**An 'int' object has no attribute 'find'.**

Now you can ask yourself the question which WORD in this statement you don't understand and try to find a definition for this word. Is it `object` you don't understand? is it `attribute`? Is it `has no`? Is it `int`? Is it `find`?

As a beginner it is worth to know about the importance of naming the used variables.

The name `i` suggests for example usually an integer value ( 0, 1, 2, 3, ... ) and the name `s` suggests a string value ( '0', '1', '2', '3', ... ). Choosing a name which does not suggest what the variable with this name actually stores can easily lead to confusion.

```
for i in contents:
```

makes out of `i` a special value being an item in the iterable `contents`. Such item (called often an 'object') comes with the `.find()` method, so it's ok to use it, but ... the `i` suggests somehow an integer value what is probably the reason of changing the for loop to:

```
for i in range(1,52):
```

and expecting it would work the same way. But it doesn't. The variable `i` stores now an integer value and integer values do not come with a `.find()` method.

Comment: Thank you Claudio, From now on, I will ask questions after fully understanding the concept. Sorry. : (

Comment: The *AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'find'* tells you exactly what the problem is: **'int' object has no attribute 'find'** . Now you can ask yourself the question which WORD in this statement you don't understand and try to find a definition for this word. Is it `object` you don't understand? is it `attribute`? Is it `has no`? Is it `int`? Is it `find`?